# How Are These Probabilities Greater than $1$ or less than $0$? Isn't This a Violation of Axioms of Probability Theory?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I came across the following statement:

> If a random variable $Y$ has a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\pi(Y ~ Bern(\pi))$, then $Y$ takes binary values
>
> $
>   Y =
>   \begin{cases}
>   1 & \text{with probability $\pi$} \\
>   0 & \text{with probability $1 - \pi$}
>   \end{cases}
> $

$\pi = 3.14...$, so I'm confused as to how we can have a probability greater than $1$ or less than $0$? This seems to be in violation of the axioms of probability theory?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: $\pi$ doesn't mean the famous constant in this context.  It is some other constant between 0 and 1.

Comment: Note:  Most people avoid using $\pi$ as a variable name for this reason...everyone assumes it refers to $3.14\dots$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you all.

Comment: $\pi$ is the Greek letter "p"$\,-\,$so in this context, it's just a letter representing a fixed, unknown probability. Why $\pi$? That's easy$\,-\,$"p" for "probability".

Comment: Along these lines there's the old "joke" about writing the general quartic as $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$.   As it stands that simple expression is actually ambiguous, because the "$e$" might be misinterpreted as the base of the natural log.  Granted, it seems more pedantic than humorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\pi$ here is a parameter in the interval $[0,1]$ representing the probability of success of a Bernoulli trial. It is not referring to the constant $3.14\ldots$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Thank you for the clarification.